# WPF: Why my DataTemplate item cannot find its parent?

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate in my *.xaml, it is the datatemplate for my listview control:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listViewSourceItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type this:SourceItemField}">
    <this:SourceItemField Background="LightPink">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,10,5,10" Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldType,StringFormat=\{0\}}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContextName,StringFormat=\{0\}}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldName,StringFormat=\{0\}}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConnectionNumber,StringFormat=\{0\}}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</this:SourceItemField>
```

In my C# code, I have following program:

```
    public void SetPosition()
    {
        Center = this.TransformToAncestor(FindAncestor<Canvas>(this)).Transform(new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2));
    }


    // walk up the visual tree for parent of type T
    private static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        do
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        while (current != null);
        return null;
    }
```

"this" is SourceItemField, why VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() return its ancestor as "null"? Why this SourceItemField's parent is not my listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to find Canvas and not the ListView as ancestor?


i.e. instead of this:

> public void SetPosition()
> {
>  
>       Center = this.TransformToAncestor(FindAncestor<**Canvas**>(this)).Transform(new
>   Point(this.ActualWidth / 2,
>   this.ActualHeight / 2));  
> }

this:

```
public void SetPosition() 
{ 
    Center = this.TransformToAncestor(FindAncestor<ListView>(this)).Transform(new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2)); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to find canvas. In fact, I have two listview(listviewSource and listviewTarget) in my canvas, and listviewSource contains source items from DataTemplate named listviewSourceItemTemplate, listviewTarget contains target items from DataTemplate named listviewTargetItemTemplate. I want to draw connection lines between one of the source item and one of the target item. And both my source item and target item are movable. So I need to update the connection lines dynamically and hence I need to know their absolute locations on my canvas.

Comment: Actually I have tried: put one source item A and one target item B on a canvas named myCanvas, I can draw connection (actually a path) dynamically between A and B. I use exactly the same function "FindAncestor" above to find A's ancestor - myCanvas. So I am confused why I use dataTemplate and listview, it doesn't work.

Comment: I am very new to WPF but I tried to search the reason: I doubt whether due to I use this dataTemplate and souceItemField is within the dataTemplate, so it cannot identify the listview as its visual parent? There are visual tree and logic tree provide hierarchy relationship between controls. So I wonder whether the visual tree will not create such hierarhy between item from dataTemplate and the listview containing this item. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Is there another way I can avoid this FindAncestor method but still findout the absolute location of my sourceFieldItem on my canvas? If I can find out the absolute location of the sourceFieldItem on the canvas, then even this sourceFieldItem still cannot find its host listview - it doesn't matter. Or is there a way I can let the sourceFieldItem find out listview is its parent and canvas is the listview's parent? I have no idea about either way. Really need help on this. Thank you all!

Comment: Don't exactly get your problem, but see if Visual.FindCommonVisualAncestor method helps. Don't try to cast it to canvas, but see the datatype of the object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.findcommonvisualancestor.aspx Additionaly, you can try using Snoop (http://www.blois.us/Snoop/) to see the visual tree of your wpf app.

Comment: Still cannot have a good solution. Looking for the other design now.

Comment: @spspli, have you tried Snoop to inspect the visual tree of your app? It might help.